# Added condition to ORDER BY statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I found this question on a website and was trying to solve it to no avail. There is a table of Nobel prize winners with columns name, year and subject. The question is this: Show the 1984 winners and subject ordered by subject and winner name; but list Chemistry and Physics last.

I came up with the following:

```
SELECT winner, subject
FROM nobel
WHERE yr=1984
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN subject NOT IN ('Chemistry','Physics') THEN 1
WHEN subject IN ('Chemistry','Physics') THEN 2
ELSE 3 END
```

which gives the result:

```
winner               subject
Richard Stone        Economics
Jaroslav Seifert     Literature
Niels K. Jerne       Medicine
Georges J.F. KÃ¶hler Medicine
CÃ©sar Milstein      Medicine
Desmond Tutu         Peace
Bruce Merrifield     Chemistry
Carlo Rubbia         Physics
Simon van der Meer   Physics
```

I however, require that the order of winners for each subject be further sorted by name i.e. the result above should become Caesar Milstein as 3rd, followed by Georges J.K. Kahler and then Niels K. Jerne.

Comment: just add the second order criteria to your `ORDER BY`: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN ......END, subject, winner`

Comment: As most people here have pointed out, adding `winner` to the `ORDER BY` clause should resolve this. However, I am running the query on the mentioned website itself; and I'm guessing (perhaps wrongly?) it is the use of MariaDB that results in a different output. In any case, the addition of `winner` to the `ORDER BY` is causing the results to be sorted only by `winner` ignoring the `subject`column.

The page I found this question on is this - sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial - Question no. 14, in case anyone is curious about the source.

Comment: SQLZOO seems happy with `SELECT winner, subject FROM nobel WHERE yr=1984 ORDER BY subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry'), subject, winner`. Note that SQL Server does not treat `IN` as an operator that returns `0` or `1`, the return type is listed as `BOOLEAN`. There is a [boolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx#Anchor_0) data type, but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a Boolean data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set."

Comment: @HABO - That's it! It works. Thank you so much. Strange that the use of `CASE` gave a faulty output. Just to clarify though - SQL Server would not give the same output for the given query?

Comment: At SQLZOO you can use `SELECT winner, subject, subject IN ('Physics', 'Chemistry') FROM nobel WHERE yr=1984 ORDER BY subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry'), subject, winner` and output a strangely named column with the result of the `IN` clause. SQL Server just has `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.` to say about that.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the winner to your order by statement:-

```
SELECT winner, subject
FROM nobel
WHERE yr=1984
ORDER BY 
CASE
WHEN subject NOT IN ('Chemistry','Physics') THEN 1
WHEN subject IN ('Chemistry','Physics') THEN 2
ELSE 3 
END,
winner
```

Answer (score 1):

Order By case When Subject in ('Chemistry', 'Physics') then 1
           else 0 end, winner, Subject

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has mentioned, you just need `,winner` added.  But you can simplify this a bit too:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN subject NOT IN ('Chemistry','Physics') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, winner
```

Comment: Your `CASE` is semantically different if `subject` can be `NULL`, i.e. the OP's `CASE` will return `3` for `NULL` values putting them at the end of the list.

Comment: @HABO Thanks, that is very true, and worth noting.  But as OP didn't mention that in any way, I find it more likely that he didn't realize he could remove that line, then that he was accounting for `NULL`

Comment: `subject` is indeed nullable, but for the sake of this question, it is assumed that there are no `NULL` fields

Answer (score 1):

I think this works

```
SELECT winner, subject,CASE
WHEN subject NOT IN ('Chemistry','Physics') THEN 1
WHEN subject IN ('Chemistry','Physics') THEN 2
ELSE 3 END ord
FROM nobel
WHERE yr=1984 
ORDER BY ord,winner ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the help. However, as I mentioned in one of the comments, the specific website I tested these queries on didn't give me an output for the answers posted here. What worked though is posted by HABO in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234260/added-condition-to-order-by-statement?noredirect=1#comment63925659_38234260).